# Mock mailer and set to container

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony

I am currently writing a PHPUnit test case for a forgot password function in symfony2.

What im trying to do is this:

- Mock a mailer class and set it in the controllers container im testing.

Here's the mock:

```
private function getMockMailer($return)
{
    $mailer = $this->getMockBuilder('Swift_Mailer')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(array('send'))
            ->getMock();

    $mailer->expects($this->any())
        ->method('send')
        ->with($this->anything())
        ->will($this->returnValue($return));

    return $mailer;
}
```

Dumping the mock object returns: "Mock_Swift_Mailer_02ed3dbc" which is correct.

But when I dump the mailer class in the controller i get "Swift_Mailer" which is not the mocked object.

And here's how i set the mailer in the test:

```
    $container = static::$kernel->getContainer();
    $mailer = $this->getMockMailer(true);

    $container->set('mailer', $mailer);

    $controller = new LoginController();
    $controller->setContainer($container);
```

I've used the same method to mock router and templating classes, and it worked fine. Mailer is the only one giving me this issue.

Any ideas are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are definitely wrong in approach of the app arcitecture. 
The approach to get service from the container is quick, but it is killing way for unit testing with mocks.

wrong:

```
$container->set('mailer', $mailer);
```

You should use Dependency Injection pattern instead

similar like you do

```
$controller->setContainer($container);
```

you should set DI of mailer

you can use https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle/tree/master with real usage

as

```
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation as DI;

class Controller
{
    /** @DI\Inject("mailer") */
    private $mailer; 

    public function setMailer($mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer; 
    }
```

But you should use "setMailer" with your unit test

```
$controller->setMailer($this->getMockMailer(true));
```

Comment: That was my initial idea, to use setter and getter for it, but i thought the service container from the test is the same container used in the controller. Obviously not :) Thanks for the suggestion, i will use this approach.